# Upper left Dini derivative of Brownian motion at a hitting time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion. Define the upper left Dini derivative $D^-W$ by

$$D^-W_t := \limsup_{h \to 0^-} \frac{W_{t+h} - W_t}{h}.$$

Fix $a > 0$, and define the stopping time $\tau$ by

$$\tau := \inf \{t > 0 \, | \, W_t \geq a\}$$

**Question:** Is it true that $D^- W_\tau = +\infty$, almost surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative is indeed infinite, basically because Brownian motion does not have points that are too regular in a sense.

A *slow point* for a realisation of Brownian motion is a time $t$ such that
$$ \sup_{h\to0^+}\frac{|W_{t+h}-W_t|}{h^{1/2}}<\infty. $$
For the purposes of this answer, let me call a *very slow point* a time $t$ such that the above supremum is (strictly) less than 1.

> **Theorem** (Davis) (Greenwood & Perkins)**.**
>
> Almost surely, the set of very slow points is empty.

It follows by time reflection that at all points, either the upper or lower left Dini derivative of Brownian motion is infinite. Since the lower left Dini derivative is zero at $\tau$, then the upper one must be infinite.

---

*A conditioned limit theorem for random walk and Brownian local time on square root boundaries,* P. Greenwood and E. A. Perkins (1983). [Link.](https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176993594)

*On Brownian slow points,* B. Davis (1983). [Link.](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00532967)

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!